# Moving Datagrid at runtime WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a StackPanel of Datagrids that contain data about various things.  A user should be able to click on one of those datagrids and that datagrid should expand and take the place of the four datagrids on the screen.  Clicking on the expanded grid should return the screen back to the previous display of four data grids.

I have tried replacing the top grid in the backend (I don't think this is a violation of MVVM since it is dealing purely with the display, but I could be wrong) with the selected grid, which doesn't seem to work. I have also tried hiding the grids to see if that would work.  I found several topics here and elsewhere talking about moving columns and/or rows around at runtime, but nothing about moving an entire datagrid at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest building your UI view as a grid with column/row sizes bound to match their content, and use a backend property to determine whether the various datagrids should be Visible or Collapsed as a result of your clicking.  Then the UI will adapt to fit the scenario you want.

Another alternative is to have a couple of views which have the explicit arrangement of controls you want, then have an outer ContentControl whose Content property is changed to one or the other as a result of the clicks.

I'd favour the former though for simplicity if feasible in your layout.